# Passing an ID over an intent

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass the ID of the clicked on data from my listview to a new activity in a second class i.e. I click the item on the `listview`.The `onListItemClick` method is called and  starts a new intent. The id is passed with the object in the `i.getExtra`. Then the id is stored into a new variable on the second class to be used later.

Ive got as far as working out how to pass the id, but I cant seem to work out how I then store it in the new variable on the second class.

Heres my code:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int list_posistion, long item_id)
{


    long id = item_id;
    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.sqliteexample.SQLView");
    i.putExtra(null, id);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Could anyone tell me how to reference it in the second class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get Bundle from Intent and then do get... to get particular element.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String id;

if (extras != null) {
    id= extras.getString("key");  //key should be what ever used in invoker.
}
```

One thing surprising is why you are using `null` as key? I would avoid using reserve words, instead use proper name like `userID` etc.,

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.sqliteexample.SQLView");
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("position", v.getTag().toString());
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
```

in second class

```
 Bundle intent= getIntent().getExtras(); 

       if (intent.getExtras() == null) {
    id= intent.getString("position");
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.
Just change :

```
i.putExtra(null, id);
```

with :

```
i.putExtra("myId", id);
```

and in the second Activity just use :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getInt("myId");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter for `Intent.putExtra()` is a String key used to identify your Extra.  Instead of `i.putExtra(null, id)` try `i.putExtra("SomeString", id)`.

Then, in the onCreate of (or anywhere within) your second activity, you can get your id back from the intent like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
long id = intent.getLongExtra("SomeString");
```

There are also methods for getting Strings, Chars, Booleans, Ints, and more complex data structures.  Check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html for more info on methods for the Intent class.